# Sum of all numbers less than equal to X relatively prime to all number less than Y

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algorithms, prime-factorization

Here's a programming question probably needing lots of math:

> Given two integers X and Y, you need to find the sum of all positive
>   integers less than or equal to X, which have no divisor smaller than
>   or equal to Y, apart from 1. Find the most efficient way to do this.

I've been thinking about it since a long time, but the best I could do was something like $O(nlgn)$ but the interviewer told me it could be done better.

My solution was to simply find all prime factors and use a slightly modified sieve to store the lowest prime factor of the number. This would take $O(sqrt(n))$ time. Now we can compute prime factors of any number in $O(lgn)$ time easily. So iterate from 1 to n, check if number has any prime factor less than Y, if yes, dont add it, otherwise add it.

Any ideas? I think this will have some kind of a direct formula.

Comment: Give your solution in $O(n\log(n))$.

Comment: @loupblanc added

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the code would help to understand the points where it could be (or not) better than it is now, but initially there is a basic point you mention that could be enhanced, in your last step:

> "So iterate from 1 to n, check if number has any prime factor less than Y, if yes, dont add it, otherwise add it."

1. You would not need to start from $1$ but from $Y+1$, because a number under or equal to $Y$ has all the divisors under or equal to $Y$, so:$$n \ge Y+1$$(only the special case $n=1$ will be in your addition by default).So any $n \in [2,Y]$ can be discarded.

Now supposing that in a first step you sieved all the primes, then:

2. Now for the interval $[Y+1,Y^2]$ you would just need to add the prime numbers inside the interval that you already sieved, not the composite numbers. This is because any composite $n$ has at least a divisor under $\sqrt{n}$, so any composite number in the interval $[Y,Y^2]$ at least has a divisor in the interval $[2,Y]$. So if you had made in a first step the sieving of the primes, you will not need to verify again any number in $[Y,Y^2]$, just directly add the primes in that interval.
3. And finally you would need to test all composite numbers in the interval $[(Y+1)^2,X]$, because some of them could have all the divisors (except $1$) over $Y$, and in the other hand you can directly add all the primes in that interval.

I hope it helps, if you add the code I could have a look, just let me know in the comments. Probably is fine as it is, specially if the interviewer did not explain any details about how to make it better.